# Почему некорректно работает fullpage.js?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Есть небольшая тестовая страничка [alexbeos.beget.tech/test](http://alexbeos.beget.tech/test)

На первом экране слева сверху есть треугольник. На сайте используется плагин fullpage.js.
Если прокрутить экран вниз, а потом опять наверх, можно увидеть, что треугольник исчез, и появляется опять. Я как понимаю, дело в том что там slick slider. Без него нормально, если просто картинку ставить. Но беда в том, что с любым слайдером такая проблема появляется. И с бутсраповским тоже. Спасибо заранее! Дело не только в треугольнике, но и в любом элементе (даже если текст вставить)

https://prnt.sc/fg64vl

Comment: Ссылка на сайт нерабочая.

Answer (score 0):

Поигрался пять минут... Если на `.slick-slider` навесить `z-index: -1`, то все будет гуд. Но это **дико костыльное** решение.

```
div.container > div.slick-slider {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

К слову, у вас верстка ни разу не адаптивная. Чуть сжал экран - уже все съезжает, картинка сжимается, белый фон... В верстке виден избыток лишних блоков-врапперов... На вашем месте я бы начал верстать с нуля и минимально использовал разные сторонние плагины.  Потому что сейчас разобраться в чем действительно причина такого мерцания будет очень проблематично.

Comment: Да там нет верстки считайте. Там просто слайдер. И все. И да, это все неадаптивно, так как просто страница с одной проблемой. Я ставил z-index: -1, но над картинкой будет текст. Ни он, ни элементы навигации тогда не работают. P.S. По поводу избычточности враперов - добавляют их слайдер и fullpage.js

Comment: @АлександрБелькевич если один плагин плохо работает с другим плагином - комбинируйте другие варианты. Либо вообще пишите свое решение, специфичное для вашей задачи...

Comment: Так любой слайдер так отрабатывает здесь. Нормального аналога fullpage не нашел. Я не думаю, что это какая-то невозможная проблема. Просто может кто-то увидит, в чем причина